# What is the reading of 四十ヵ国

Tags: readings

Would it be よんじゅうかこくor start with しじゅう?

If anyone cares, the sentence was
俺は全世界四十ヵ国に支店を持つ、大企業の社長だった。
I was the president of a large corporation with branches in forty countries around the world.

It appeared in the following volume:
Author:青山章二 (Aoyama Shōji), title: びん ("Bottle") in 星新一 (Shin'ichi Hoshi, editor) ショートショートの広場 (Shōto shōto no hiroba) ISBN-13 : 978-4061835559, page 192

Comment: It's よんじゅっかこく or よんじっかこく.(Too short to answer)

Comment: What does "Too short to answer" mean? Should I have quoted the passage at greater length for more context or were you rushing to catch a bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, 四 can only be read as し when it directly precedes a counter--if there are intervening numbers, it's よん. So 40, 400, etc., nearly always use よん. There are rare exceptions for numbers in the forty range, as described [here](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/counting-in-japanese/), but since your question isn't about an archaic set phrase, it's going to be よん.